# Likelihood ratio test for limit model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Is it possible to use a likelihood ratio test for the case when we compare a model $M$ and a model $M_0$, where $M_0$ is obtained when a positive parameter $\theta \to 0$. This is, $M_0$ is a limit model rather than just a nested model.

Comment: So a limit model means that you are taking the same model where a parameter is set to 0 at the limit? In that case at the limit the restricted model is nested with respect to the initial model. Right? So what’s the actual difference? Or am I misunderstanding something maybe?

Comment: Do you have a specific case in mind--or, at least an example for illustration?

Comment: @Fr1 Correct. However, in this case, the "nested" model is achieved at a limit, which is not an interior point. So, I was wondering if all of the asymptotic results required to used the likelihood ratio test are actually satisfied.

Comment: @BruceET It is a generic question. I could formulate it using a more particular example, but I am not sure if this would simplify any aspect of the question.

Comment: The limit's not an interior point, but is it on the boundary of the parameter space?  (You wrote "positive" in the question, so I'm guessing not...)

Comment: @jbowman Imagine a scale parameter, and take the limit when that scale parameter converges to zero. OK, you can define it as the closure of the parameter space, or as a limit, where the limit might be a Dirac Delta, which is a more complicated (generalized) model/distribution (being more technical than grammatical).